# Sum of column containing both decimal numbers and integers

Tags: php, sql

My table `debit_details` has a column `debit` (varchar(40)).

I insert Excel data into the table, like this:

```
 id           debit

 1             462
 2             1,07,500.00
 3             1,00,000.00
 4             7,022.00
 5             850
 6             1,708.00
 7              392.8
 8              11.4
 9              20,000.00
10              1,35,100.00
11              6,350.00
```

I want to get sum of total debit:

```
SELECT SUM(debit) as debit FROM debit_details
```

I expect the sum of debit to be 379396.2, but I am getting sum 1753.2.

Comment: Get rid of commas...

Answer (score 2):

Here is the possibility you can try

```
SELECT SUM(REPLACE(debit,',','')) as debit FROM `debit_details`
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove commas from numbers.

```
SELECT  462
      + 107500.00
      + 100000.00
      + 7022.00
      + 850
      + 1708.00
      + 392.8
      + 11.4
      + 20000.00
      + 135100.00
      + 6350.00
```

Result:

```
379396.20
```